# Git, deleting repository

Tags: git

I somewhat screwd up the file system of my remote node. I am doing a project and the remote repo was initialized by my instructor. I cloned it and then pushed the updates from my home directory.

I now want to delete the repo which I cloned in the remote server. I want to start it over.

How do I delete the repository which was cloned before?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A repository is just a directory with working copy (though it is optional) and `.git`, so deleting the directory deletes the repository. To delete a remote repository you need to have access to the remote filesystem.

Comment: I deleted the local dir from my laptop. However, I want to delete the repo from the server which is assigned for me.

Comment: Delete it then. If you don't have a shell access or anything else suitable for deleting the directory with the repo, you cannot do that.

Comment: I am using git bash to log in to the remote server. What is the command to delete a repo from the server?

Answer (score 11):

By the way, You can remove your .git

`rm -rf .git`

Alternative to killing TortioseGit:
Open the TortoiseGit-Settings (right click to any folder, TortoiseGit → Settings)
Go to the Icon Overlays option.
Change the Status Cache from Default to None
Now you can delete the directory (either with Windows Explorer or `rmdir /S /Q`)
Set back the Status Cache from None to Default and you should be fine again...

If Your're using gitHub:

https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository

Comment: well I am still having problem and not sure why this is happening. I am new to git. I pused the updated file from my laptop to the server by using GIT gui. However whenever I open the file by loggin in to the server, I dont see any change. I am not getting it why its behaving like this.

Comment: finally a solution, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

1. Click the repository in your GitHub account
2. Click "Settings" in the bottom right corner
3. Click "Delete the repository" at the bottom.

Comment: This one worked for me perfectly fine, directly from my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the remote server and do a file system delete.